# How to do DB partitioning on a field in django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have django model with mutiple fields, and it is mapped to a MySQL DB, now there is a datetime field in the model, in which i would like to set [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html).

The model looks like this:

```
class Packet(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    packet_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    # Location Details
    signal = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='A')
    lat = models.FloatField(default=None, null=True)
    lat_indicator = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='')
    lng = models.FloatField(default=None, null=True)
    lng_indicator = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='NA')
    speed = models.FloatField(default=None, null=True)
    orientation = models.FloatField(default=None, null=True)
    #House Keeping Items
    dor = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now()) # <= Want to partition this for weekly basis. 
    dirty = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Please advice me how this can be achieved.

Comment: I think, you need to use package for Django. Not sure.
These are the packages that you can use :-

https://github.com/danfairs/django-parting
--------------
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-parti#id2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Max, `django-db-parti` is deprecated in favor of [architect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/architect). The Github link is available [here](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/architect), with further documentation available on [readthedocs](http://architect.readthedocs.org/)

---

Original Answer:

The [django-db-parti](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-parti) package exists, which seems to meet your criteria. Github link [here](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/django-db-parti).

The MySQL portion of the document states:

> MySQL's partitioning implementation in Django DB Parti is done in a
> mixed way, half at the python level and half at the database level.
> Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support dynamic sql in triggers or
> functions that are called within triggers, so the only way to create
> partitions automatically is to calculate everything at the python
> level, then to create needed sql statements based on calculations and
> issue that statement into the database.

And has the following limitations

> - Not all partitioning types are supported. New types will be added in next releases of Django DB Parti.
> - Partitioning is not available for bulk inserts (i.e. Django's bulk_create() method) because it doesn't call model's save() method
>   which this backend relies on. Currently there is no known way to
>   remove this limitation.
> - New partitions can be created only from lower to higher, you can overcome this with MySQL's special command REORGANIZE PARTITION which
>   you have to issue from the database console. You can read more about
>   it at the MySQL's documentation. We plan to remove this limitation in
>   one of the future releases of Django DB Parti.

The [configuration](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-parti#configuration) of your partition occurs in your model's Meta class.

Comment: Just a note that django-db-parti is deprecated in favour of Architect package.  PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/architect  Github: https://github.com/maxtepkeev/architect  Docs: http://architect.readthedocs.org

Comment: You should also note that postgres supports native partitioning now without the need for triggers, and this is a way better solution with https://github.com/chaitin/django-pg-partitioning on Python3 + Django 2+